# on a level so far as nearness to truth is concerned

Tags: grammar, meaning

> Is there no such thing as truth? Of course there is—and men are
> getting nearer to it. For different outlooks, partisan as they may be,
> are not **on a level so far as nearness to truth is concerned**. Every
> philosophy embodies a class outlook.

[Maurice Cornforth, Materialism and Dialectical method]

What does "on a level so far as nearness to truth is concerned" mean? I find it difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent meaning - 'different outlooks are not equally near truth' - seems clear enough, but the use of 'on a level' ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/on_a_level_with) - [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20a%20level)) to mean [on a par with](https://www.lexico.com/definition/par):

```
Equal in importance or quality to
```

is unusual; as is the use of the conjunction '[so far as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20far%20as)' ('to the extent that') rather than the preposition [as far as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20far%20as):

```
 with regard to : concerning
```

> For different outlooks, partisan as they may be, are not equal in
> importance or quality with regard to nearness to truth.